# ¿Cómo actualizar los modelos relacionados antes de actualizar un modelo en mongooose?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

¿Cómo se puede relacionar el modelo de base de datos en mongodb usando mongoose? Es decir, voy a crear un libro, le paso todos los valores necesarios, nombre, etc, pero quiero saber como hago si al guardar el libro, también quiero que se inserte la información del libro, por ejemplo el id o título. Estos son los dos esquemas:

```
var autor = new Schema({  
    nombre: String,
    biografia: String,
    fecha_de_nacimiento: Date,
    nacionalidad: String
    books: [{
    libro: {
      titulo: String,
      ref: 'libro'
    },
    funciones: String
  }],
});

var libro = new Schema({  
    titulo: String    
    paginas: Number,
    isbn: String,
    autor: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Autor" } 
});
```

Para crear el libro haría algo así:

```
var libro = new libro({
    titulo: req.body.titulo,
    paginas: req.body.paginas,
    isbn: req.body.isbn,
});

libro.save(function(err, tvshow) {
    if(err) return res.status(500).send( err.message);
    res.status(200).json(libro);
});
```

Pero, ¿cómo inserto la información, por ejemplo el id y el título del libro en el modelo del autor?

Answer (score 3):

Lo que estas intentando crear es una relación de uno a muchos, un libro tiene un autor y un autor tiene muchos libros (deberías modelarlo para que pueda tener más de uno, de muchos a muchos).

Expresar la relación en el libro es fácil sólo usa un `Schema.ObjectId` y usa `ref` para indicarle a mongoose cual es el modelo que debe usar

```
var libroSchema = new Schema({  
    titulo: String    
    paginas: Number,
    isbn: String,
    autor: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Autor" } 
});
```

Para el autor necesitas un arreglo ya que pueden ser 0 o más elementos.

> Permite la creacción de arreglos de [SchemaTypes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) o [Sub-Documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html).

```
// Ejemplo usando un subdocumento
var autorSchema = new Schema({  
    nombre: String,
    biografia: String,
    fecha_de_nacimiento: Date,
    nacionalidad: String
    libros: [libroSchema]
});
```

Para actualizarlo este es un ejemplo

```
var autor = new Autor({nombre: 'Miguel de Cervantes', libros: [ {titulo: 'El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha'}, {titulo: 'La Galatea'}]});
autor.save(/*...Manejo de errores...*/);
```

El problema de usar un subdocumento es que estos sólo son actualizados cuando el documento padre es actualizado por lo que sólo es una buena solución si quieres mantenerlos como datos independientes dentro de otros documentos, no como datos relacionados.

La forma correcta de expresar estas relaciones es usar simples referencias e invocar al método [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) cuando quieras obtener todos los datos.

> No existen los joins en MongoDB pero a veces aun se desea referenciar documentos en otras colecciones. En esto casos es cuando `population` se usa.

Esto es lo que se conoce en otros frameworks como hidratar.

```
// Ejemplo usando populate y ObjectId
var autorSchema = new Schema({  
    nombre: String,
    biografia: String,
    fecha_de_nacimiento: Date,
    nacionalidad: String
    libros: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Libro"}]
});
```

y luego para obtener el objeto autor con todos sus datos relacionados

```
var Autor = mongoose.model('Autor', autorSchema)

Autor
    .findOne({ nombre: 'Miguel de Cervantes'})
    .populate('libros')
    .exec(function (err, autor) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        // la variable autor contiene los datos del autor y sus libros escritos
     });
```

Para actualizar los libros de un autor solo necesitas sus `_id`. Siguiendo el ejemplo anterior

```
var quijote = new Libro({titulo: 'El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha'});
var galatea = new Libro({titulo: 'La Galatea'});
quijote.save(/*... manejo de errores..*/);
galatea.save(/*... manejo de errores..*/);


.exec(function (err, autor) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    autor.libros = [quijote._id, galatea._id];
    autor.save(function(err) {
        // se actualizaron los datos del autor
    });
});
```

Ten en cuenta que para crear Modelos debes usar mayúsculas para que se distingan claramente por eso yo adicioné el sufijo *Schema* a mis variables (libroSchema y autorSchema) para que no se me confundan con los modelos ya que estos son [schemas](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) que se usan para crear [Modelos](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html). Es muy importante entender la diferencia.

Comment: @LLaza No te olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió